# Controll Room output from audio mixture as a mic to Mobile phone

Tags: audio, sound-card, audio-streaming

A local discourse group nearby me uses PreSonus StudioLive AR8 USB 8-Channel hybrid Performance and Recording Mixer during discourse meetings every week with offline audiences. This is the picture of that device.

[image]

This device has the option to connect to the laptop using the USB cable but for some reason, the USB is not recognized in windows or MAC devices, also after installing the drivers and software. And also the people that manage this device are not tech-savvy, they don't have any software knowledge.

So, I am thinking of an easy way to use the output from this mixer to connect to the mobile which further can be used to live stream to social sites.

For that, I am thinking to connect **Dual 6.35mm 1/4 " TS** cable, to the left and right of the Control Room on the mixer, and 3.5mm 1/8 " TRS to the audio splitter.

[image]

Further, I will use a Y splitter adapter and connect the 3.55mm jack on the MICROPHONE input.

[image: Y splitter]

After that, I will connect that 3.5mm jack to type c using this adapter, and to the mobile.

[image]

Will this option work? Does this setup have any chance of destroying any devices? What will be the output with this setup?

I cannot play around with this Mixture to try out the different options I need to be prepared already before trying out the devices. And It's hard to purchase the wires and cable due to the limited budget.

Please suggest some other viable alternative to stream the audio from this mixture to social sites.

Answer (score 0):

1. It either needs drivers, or possibly this software - https://www.presonus.com/products/StudioLive-AR8-USB/downloads - otherwise it's likely just USB standard device-compliant & doesn't need drivers.
2. Aside from the level & impedance-matching issues you'll face, a phone's headset input is mono. To get stereo [& line level-matching] You'll need something like this, from IK Multimedia - https://www.ikmultimedia.com/products/?S1=491 - then you can just run jack to jack.

[image]

Comment: Installing the driver and the software didn't help, also, unfortunately, people who used this mixture don't have laptops. :( :(

Comment: Not sure what laptops have to do with it. If you want to connect it to a phone, without using USB, you need an interface. The actual USB connection is very probably just device-compliant, so without further info as to exactly what the setup is, we can't help. Get in touch with PreSonus - it's their device, they should support it for their customers.